# Firebase createCustomToken() returns an invalid token in local emulators

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, jwt, firebase-tools

I am using firebase authentication to handle user accounts for my web application. When a user enters valid login credentials I am using the firebase admin SDK to generate a JWT in a cloud function, which is sent back to the client and then authenticated with firebase. I am running into an issue where the JWT generated by the firebase admin SDK is invalid. More specifically, when the token is decoded (I used [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)), I get the following:

```
Header: {
  "alg": "none",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

Payload: {
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "iat": 1614367953,
  "exp": 1614371553,
  "iss": "firebase-auth-emulator@example.com",
  "sub": "firebase-auth-emulator@example.com",
  "uid": "some uid here"
}
```

The token is not only missing a signature, but the *iss* and *sub* values are wrong. I am using `admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)` to generate the token and the app is being initialized with a valid service account that has Service Token Creation privileges.

EDIT:
I have just figured out that the token is generated incorrectly only while everything is run locally using firebase emulators. When I deploy the app, the token is generated and validated just fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's great that this isn't an issue in production, but it should never be an issue in development either. You end up having a different dev env to your prod env which makes testing less robust.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are [instrumenting your app to talk to the authentication emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#instrumentauth) ... and doing it *before* the authentication listeners do their thing.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error only if i try to verify the token generated by `createCustomToken`.

If you pass the token to `signInWithCustomToken` in the client app then get the user token with `auth.currentUser.getIdToken` your will notice the token is slightly different and claims are the expected ones.

You can then verify this token in your backend and no errors will show up.