# CreateCustomToken() via Firebase Auth Emulator has "alg":"none" in JWT token, making it unverifiable via Firebase Admin SDK or custom JWT Verifier

Tags: node.js, firebase, go, firebase-authentication, jwt

**Context:**

I'm using a Node Cloud Function with the Firebase Admin SDK to create a custom token (via emulators when testing locally).
That token is sent to a React Application where it is consumed and converted to an IdToken.
Then that token is being attemped to be used as an auth token to a Golang REST server where I'm trying to verify it with the Firebase Admin SDK

**Problem:**

For some strange reason beyond my reasoning, whenever I try to generate a custom firebase token via my Local Auth Emulator inside of a Locally Emulated Cloud Function, the header for `"alg"` seems to always be `"none"`. This is not the case when the function is deployed.

Example code of token generation: `admin.auth().createCustomToken(request.body.username...`

The following screenshot represents the decoded contents of the TokenId (you get it when you sign in with the generated token and call `.getIdToken()` from the obtained user)

[image: decoded token]

This specific ID Token, lacks the "kid" header in the payload, making it useless against the `VerifyIDTokenAndCheckRevoked()` in the Golang Admin SDK (already tried).

And will also be invalidated with a custom JWT verifier, since the "alg" is `none`, and it is established as not allowed by default. (represented error: `token is unverifiable: 'none' signature type is not allowed`)
The following code represents the custom verifier:

```golang
func (s *authService) VerifyToken(ctx context.Context, token string) (*CustomClaims, error) {
    var customClaims *CustomClaims

    parsedToken, err := jwt.Parse(token, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        // It doesn't work even with this validation commented...
        if val, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("> Wrong signing method: %v", token.Method.Alg())
        } else {
            if val.Alg() != "RS256" {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("> Unexpected signing method: %v", val.Alg())
            }
        }

        // In order to be able to decode the token manually, we need to give the private key to the Parse function
        hmacSecret := []byte(os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS_PRIVATE_KEY"))
        return hmacSecret, nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, jwt.ErrTokenMalformed) {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("> Malformed authentication: %s", err.Error())
        } else if errors.Is(err, jwt.ErrTokenExpired) || errors.Is(err, jwt.ErrTokenNotValidYet) {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("> Expired authentication token: %s", err.Error())
        } else {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("> Something is wrong with the authentication: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }

    if claims, ok := parsedToken.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && parsedToken.Valid {
        byteClaims, err := json.Marshal(claims)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        err = json.Unmarshal(byteClaims, customClaims)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        return customClaims, nil

    }
    
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("> Something is wrong with the authentication claims")
    

    /* Deprecated method due to custom token verification issue (no kid header) with Admin SDK*/
    // client, err := s.app.Auth(ctx)
    // if err != nil {
    //  return nil, err
    // }

    // authToken, err := client.VerifyIDTokenAndCheckRevoked(ctx, token)
    // if err != nil {
    //  return nil, err
    // }

}
```

**Is there any workaround for this blockage?**

Maybe allowing the emulators to sign the token with the correct "alg" header, or maybe skipping the "alg" validation in the Custom JWT Verifier?

I've seen another similar question about this, but it doesn't come to a solution:
[Firebase createCustomToken() returns an invalid token in local emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392144/firebase-createcustomtoken-returns-an-invalid-token-in-local-emulators)

**UPDATE**:

Attempted to create my own implementation of the JWT token generation, to no avail. It seems that I was able to generate a fully working token, but whenever I want to get an **IdToken** (the one that firebase truly authenticates), it's converted to a non-working token with "alg":"none".

For instance, I've determined that I'm doing everything right on my end, but Firebase IdToken generator is the one that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth Emulator does not sign JWT tokens, it's by design.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#id_tokens

> For security reasons, the Authentication emulator issues unsigned ID tokens, which are only accepted by other Firebase emulators, or the Firebase Admin SDK when configured.

But you can create and verify tokens with Admin SDK.

To make it work with Admin SDK, you must set environment variable for emulator host to emulator url:

```
FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:9099
```

If you are using Admin SDK emulator from different hosts/servers, you must set on both sides this variable to point to your emulator host.